# Docker Swarm on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is Docker Swarm supported on Docker for Mac?

When I try to use Docker Swarm I get an error:

```
$ docker swarm init
docker swarm init is only supported on a Docker cli with swarm features enabled
```

I need Docker Swarm on my local Mac to test Docker features which are only available for Docker Swarm (e.g. [Config Maps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/)).

This question is also asked in the [docker community forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-swarm-init-is-only-supported-on-a-docker-cli-with-swarm-features-enabled/44422). But no answer is provided there.

Comment: It should work. Check the "About Docker" view to make sure you have a version that supports it. From that forum link it also suggests you check that Kubernetes is turned off.

Comment: You're right: The solution is to turn off kubernetes.  I missed the real answer in in that forum link. SO is just better there. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Please comment problems about my question, when downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work in current versions of Docker for Mac. Check the "About Docker" view to make sure you have a version that supports it (Docker engine >= 1.13 or Docker CE).

It appears right now that you need Kubernetes support turned *off* ([see forum post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-swarm-init-is-only-supported-on-a-docker-cli-with-swarm-features-enabled/44422)), so check that in the settings as well.

Answer (score 4):

1. You may disable Kubernetes by navigating to the Preferences pane
   [image]
2. If you would like to use Swarm simultaneously with Kubernetes, you need to set the DOCKER_ORCHESTRATOR env variable to switch to Swarm.
   So open a new terminal, 
   `export DOCKER_ORCHESTRATOR=swarm`

   `docker swarm init`

Comment: this answer saved my day, I was try to install openfaas on docker swarm but there was error but I could able to solve it with this answer